# Sending Parameterized DSN into ADO.Net Destination

Tags: postgresql, ssis, connection

I'm currently using SSIS in Visual Studio 2019 with deployment into a SSISDB Agent on SQL Server 2019.  I do not have admin access to the Server.

I am trying to parameterize an ADO.NET Destination that connects to an AWS PostgresQL database.  The connection string uses a 32 bit ODBC System based DSN ("DSN=SERVER" minus the quotes is the entirety of the connection string being used, when displayed in the parameter, it is only "SERVER" minus the quotes.)

The error I'm receiving is not a numbered error.  It is "The connection string is not valid.  It must consist of one or more components of the form X=Y".  I know the connection string is working because I can preview the data when in the edit window of the ADO.NET destination and the Parameterized connection string is used, but when I try to run the system, it drops out as soon as the Execute phase starts.

Is there a way to send a parameterized Connection String to an ADO.NET?

Comment: To clarify, are you trying to parameterize the destination component "parameterize an ADO.NET Destination" or are you trying to parameterize the Connection Manager, which is an ado.net\Odbc Data Provider, which is then used by the ADO.NET destination?

Comment: I'm trying to parameterize the Connection Manager inside the ADO.NET Destination (I'm using the ADO.NET because of the fact that it is a ODBC connection.)